# django hidden field error

Tags: django, forms, field, hidden

i'm building a message system for a virtual community, but i can't take the userprofile id

i have in views.py

```
def save_message(request):
   if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
           new_obj.sender = request.user
           u = UserProfile.objects.get(request.POST['userprofile_id'])
           new_obj.owner = u
           new_obj.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect('.')    
   else:
           form = MessageForm()     
   return render_to_response('messages/messages.html', {
           'form': form,
           }, 
          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and the template:

```
{% block primary %}
<form action="." method="post">
    {{ form.as_p }}
<p><input type="hidden" value="{{ userprofile.id }}" name = "owner" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Send Message!" /></p>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

forms.py:

```
class MessageForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
          model = Messages
          fields = ['message']
```

models.py:

```
class Messages(models.Model):
     message = models.CharField(max_length = 300)
     read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
     owner = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
     sender = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I don't figure out why i get this error,since i'm just trying to get the profileId of a user, using a hiddeen field.

the error is:

```
Key 'UserProfile_id' not found in <QueryDict: {u'owner': [u''], u'message': [u'fdghjkl']}>
```

and i'm getting it after i fill out the message text field.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
           u = UserProfile.objects.get(request.POST['owner'])
```

because the input's name is 'owner!!

Comment: yes. u're right. but now, i get another error: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: you need to specifiy the attribute:  
u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=request.POST['owner'])

Comment: it says now:  invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: u = UserProfile.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST['owner']))  :)

Comment: The problem arises because there's an empty string in your request dict with key 'owner', so i suppose it is populated wrongly before! (i don't see where 'userprofile.id' in your form should come from, therefore {{ userprofile.id }} prints an empty string, i do not exactly now what you'Re tying to achieve, but i think you need to get that value somewhere in your view and put it in the context for your form!!

Comment: Question: if i have a function view named userprofile, how can i get the id of each userprofile without passing it as a parameter to the function view? i need it in the context of userprofile, so that i can pass it in the url of my 'send a message' link.
thanks!

Comment: I think what you want to achieve is have a link for sending a message to a certain user? so you could put the user-id at the end of the url as a get-parameter, eg. ?user_id=x (i guess you will have to append this to the links from your userprofile for sending a message), and then get this get-variable in the called view with user_id = request.GET['user_id'].

Comment: ythis is what i want to achieve.
Through that GET parameter, i am getting the user whos profile belongs to (and the destinatar of the message), and not the currently logged in user(the sender of the message)?
thanks so much!

Comment: You need to put something like "<a href='sendmessage/?user_id={{ user.pk }}'" in the template of the user profile! (dont know what your url for that is exactly, maybe it'll be '/appname/send.....', and you should have the user object somewhere in the context of this page, i assumed it's user, but if it's something else, put the right id in the link--and this has nothing to do with the currently logged in user)

Answer (score 0):

Can you set raise(raise Exception,request.POST) before string:  u = UserProfile.objects.get(request.POST['userprofile_id'])

And show me output.

Comment: hello, thanks so much for support, i've just figured out how it should be done, and i'll try to post the final code,for those who might have the same problem :)